# Nmap not running script

Tags: nmap

I can't seem to get nmap brute force to work. I ran a scan with nmap which told me there is an open http port. This is just an example though, I've never got it to work. Anyways, I run this script:
`nmap -p 81 --script rlogin-brute <IP>` on the the target.
But unlike what it's supposed to to, this is the only response I am getting:

```
Host is up (0.070s latency).
PORT   STATE SERVICE
81/tcp open  hosts2-ns
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.01 seconds
```

What am I doing wrong here? Like I said, I always get the same thing, no matter what script I am running or if it's tcp, ftp, http etc.

Thanks

Comment: Here's a couple of ideas: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/87023/how-to-run-nmap-http-scripts-on-unusual-ports

Answer (score 0):

You are using the [`rlogin-brute`](https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/rlogin-brute.html) script, which works with the `rlogin` Unix service on port 513. Because the service name `hosts2-ns` and number 81 do not match, the script will not run. If you happen to know that the `rlogin` service is really running on this port, then adding `-sV` to your scan will detect the service and allow the script to run.

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem to matter which script etc I'm running. Here's another one where I'm running http-proxy-brute and get this response:  PORT     STATE SERVICE

8080/tcp open  http-proxy



Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.32 seconds

Comment: That port is likely not hosting a HTTP proxy service which requires or accepts authentication. Add `-d` to your scan to get some more detailed info about why it might not be working. More generally, have some idea of what the services are you are trying. Why are you trying to brute-force credentials at all?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [portrule](http://%20https://github.com/nmap/nmap/blob/master/scripts/rlogin-brute.nse#L37):

```
portrule = shortport.port_or_service(513, "login", "tcp")
```

This means that it needs to detect port 513 as open. Since you specified `-p 81`, you're only scanning port 81 (bypassing 513).

Answer (score -1):

You can't just pick which port you want to use no matter what servive if any is running on it and use a script developed for a different port and service.